# How can I make my export file export a bigger table

Tags: php, mysql

My export file can only export a limited amount of data. That's why I only export the rows beginning from where the uuid from event is bigger or equal to 772345. But there's a lot of more data in the table. Does anyone have an idea to be able to export the whole table?

This is the export file I'm using:

```
    <?php
$db_con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "monitoring");
$result = $db_con->query('SELECT * FROM event where uuid >= 772345 and host != "" ');
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
$num_fields = mysqli_num_fields($result);
$headers = array();
while ($fieldinfo = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
    $headers[] = $fieldinfo->name;
}
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv'); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="event.csv"');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    fputcsv($fp, $headers);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
    die;
}
?>
```

This is the error I get when I try to export it all:
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1146880 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\exports\export_event_all.php on line 3

Comment: What is it that is limiting you to this smaller selection?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Is it time execution your problem ? Memory limit maybe ? You cannot do it async with pheanstalk for example ?

Comment: If you tell us what the real problem is **then we might be able to help** Are you still there??????

Comment: @RiggsFolly This is the error i get when I try to export it all: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1146880 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\exports\export_event_all.php on line 3

Comment: you're running out of memory. If you can change your server settings, try increasing the memory limit (asuming more physical memory exists and won't compromise the server's other duties). You might also have to consider writing to a temporary file instead of the output buffer, and then serving that file for download. That way, less data will be buffered in memory.

Comment: @ADyson thx, i solved by changing the settings in php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution would have been to tell the `mysqli_` extension not to buffer the results of the query. By default the query result is returned to PHP and all the rows are stored in an array in PHP memory.

You can turn this mode off using a parameter on the

```
$db_con->query('SELECT * FROM event where host != ""', MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
```

> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php
>
> From the manual
>
> Queries are using the buffered mode by default. This means that query results are immediately transferred from the MySQL Server to PHP and then are kept in the memory of the PHP process. This allows additional operations like counting the number of rows, and moving (seeking) the current result pointer. It also allows issuing further queries on the same connection while working on the result set. The downside of the buffered mode is that larger result sets might require quite a lot memory. The memory will be kept occupied till all references to the result set are unset or the result set was explicitly freed, which will automatically happen during request end the latest. The terminology "store result" is also used for buffered mode, as the whole result set is stored at once.
>
> Unbuffered MySQL queries execute the query and then return a resource while the data is still waiting on the MySQL server for being fetched. This uses less memory on the PHP-side, but can increase the load on the server. Unless the full result set was fetched from the server no further queries can be sent over the same connection. Unbuffered queries can also be referred to as "use result".
>
> Following these characteristics buffered queries should be used in cases where you expect only a limited result set or need to know the amount of returned rows before reading all rows. Unbuffered mode should be used when you expect larger results.

So if you change the `query()` like this it will work

```
<?php
$db_con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "monitoring");
$result = $db_con->query('SELECT * FROM event where host != ""', MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
//  the change                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
$num_fields = $result->field_count;
$headers = array();
while ($fieldinfo = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
    $headers[] = $fieldinfo->name;
}
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv'); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="event.csv"');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    fputcsv($fp, $headers);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
    die;
}
?>
```

Comment: This works indeed, thx. This may also be handy if want to share the script with someone else. This way they don't have to change their php.ini

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing 
    ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
    ; http://php.net/memory-limit
    memory_limit=128MB
to
    ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
    ; http://php.net/memory-limit
    memory_limit=-1
in C:\xampp\php\php.ini